# Mongoose Model.find doesn't want to find a document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js

I am trying to test my Workout model but the Workout.find query doesn't return documents.

Here is my test:

```
  1 var assert = require('chai').assert;
  2 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
  3 var database = require('../../config/database').connect;
  4
  5 var Workout = require('../../app/models/user');
  6 var workout: any;
  7
  8 describe('Workout Model', function() {
  9
 10   before(function(done) {
 11     Workout.findOne({
 12       "_id": "57cdb3e3f230e827daa0636b"
 13     }, function(err: any, doc: any) {
 14       console.log(doc);
 15       assert.isNull(err);
 16       workout = doc;
 17       done();
 18     });
 19   });
 20
 21
 22   it('can find a workout', function(done) {
 23     Workout.findOne({
 24       "days": 4,
 25       "minutes": 45,
 26       "experience": "intermediate",
 27       "goal": "gain_muscle"
 28     }, function (err: any, newWorkout: any) {
 29       assert.isNull(err);
 30       console.log(newWorkout);
 31       assert.equal(newWorkout, workout);
 32       done();
 33     });
 34   });
 35
 36 });
```

Test result:

```
Workout Model
null
null
      ✓ can find a workout
```

Here is mongoose schema:

```
  1 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
  2
  3 var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
  4
  5 var workoutSchema = new Schema({
  6
  7   days: Number,
  8   minutes: Number,
  9   experience: String,
 10   goal: String,
 11   workoutSplit: Schema.Types.Mixed
 12 });
 13
 41
 42 module.exports = mongoose.model('Workout', workoutSchema);
```

Database config file:

```
  1 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
  2
  3 var uri = 'mongodb://localhost/test'
  4
  5 function connect() {
  6   mongoose.connect(uri);
  7 }
  8
  9 exports.uri = uri;
 10 exports.connect = connect();
```

Here is a picture of the database from Robomongo:

[image]

The test passes but the console.log outputs null. Can someone help me and tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you get any error?

Comment: Nope. Both err and newWorkout were null.

Comment: Can you try with `find()` instead of `findOne`?

Comment: I tried it and it returns an empty array.

Comment: I just did. Do you see the problem now?

Comment: Does it work when you use less fields? Do the strings have padding that isn't visible? Does the same query work from the Mongo shell?

Comment: The same exact query works in the express router.

Comment: And you're not mocking Mongoose in your tests, or something?

Comment: I just updated the question with the full test. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the right server and database?

Comment: Yes. Because I have two other unit tests that use the same .connect function.

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like you're connecting to the DB at any point.  Somewhere in your code you need to call `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()`, and from what I can tell you're not.

Comment: I am doing in on `3 var database = require('../../config/database').connect;` It is in another module. When i tried putting `mongoose.connect()` in the test file it said I was trying to open an unclosed connection.

Comment: The contents of your config file were not something you were showing in the question when I answered this.

Answer (score -1):

Use findById method when using id to find the docs

[Refer here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html)

Id field in database is of type objectId and not string

Comment: show config/database file and try printing error inside each callback too

Comment: try console.log(database) inside describe

Comment: It says undefined. I just updated the question with the database config file

Comment: Try storing mongoose.model into variable and export that variable in your schema file

Comment: I did it and it still didnt help.